# Error: read tcp x.x.x.x:8080 i/o timeout

Tags: go, tcp, server

I have an HTTP server running on a VPS, this server serves a lot of requests per minute, so I imagine that's why it might have some load on him.
After a day of the server running, I start getting these errors in the output log:

```
error : read tcp x.x.x.x:8080->x.x.x.x:55992: i/o timeout
```

And only when I close the app and reopen it, it's working again.
But then again, after a day or sometimes a few hours, the same error comes back.

What could cause this error? And what can I do to avoid it stopping the server from functioning until restarting it?

Thank you upfront.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at how many connections the process has open when it starts to timeout. It may be surpassing ulimits. If that's the case consider increasing ulimits or adjusting keep-alive settings to close connections faster.

Comment: @Verran how can i increase ulimits?

Comment: @user850019: I'm sure there are hundreds of ulimit questions and answers between here and ServerFault (or just Google). You should also see what's tying up your connections, as you may not be releasing them correctly.